How do i pass a list as context to llama using groq
I am building a pdf chatbot, while retrieving relevant documents based on query from a FAISS vector db it returns the relevant docs as a list. Llama does not take list as an input. I could use openai api since that takes list as an input, but it's paid and this is just a hobby project to understand rag so i dont want to spend.
#Template to direct the agent
rag_tempalte = """
Answer the question based only on the following context:
{context}
Be concise
Question: {question}
"""
#Parsing query and relevant data
rag_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(rag_tempalte)
rag_chain = (
    {"context": docs, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
    | rag_prompt
    | llm
    | StrOutputParser()
)

TypeError: Expected a Runnable, callable or dict.Instead got an unsupported type: <class 'list'>
Is there any other free api that takes list as an input or can i make FAISS output relevant docs as a dict?
Tried to pass list of relevant documents as context to LLama, resulted in error since it does not take lists as an input.
